# Remove all rows except containing "XYZ"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to remove all rows in a `.txt` using regex in Notepad2. Example:

Remove all rows not containing the word `Engineer`:

```
Erik, 35, CEO
John, 24, Engineer
Stan, 22, Sales
Bill, 21, Operations
Katie, 31, Sales
```

Is there a simple solution to this problem ?

Comment: To almost every problem there is a solution but you have to work/learn for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match those rows:

```
^(?!.*?Engineer).*$
```

and then replace with empty string `""`.

Comment: You most likely need to use the `m` modifier ...

Comment: @HamZa Actually no need, he is using Notepad++ which is the default. It is actually the default in most text editors. I tested it in Notepad++ and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Well the `m` modifier is not enabled by default. It's just that `.` doesn't match newline by default, nice catch though

Comment: @HamZa I know that `.` doesn't match newline by default, but as I said in most text editors `^` and `$` match the start and end of each line by default, plus you can't find an option in Notepad++ to enable this or disable it.

Comment: You could enable it by including `(?m)` in your expression. You could also set the `i` modifier using `(?i)`. You could combine them `(?mi)`. You could also disable it `(?-i)`. You could also enable and disable it in the same expression `(?i)lol(?-i)lol`. Ah I love regex :D

Comment: @HamZa I love them too. I think Notepad++ uses the PCRE library. Does PCRE support inline flags ?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However, I had to install Notepad++ since it didn't work in Notepad2.

Comment: @JimmyPersson You are very welcome ! are Notepad2 and Notepad++ a different thing !! I didn't know that. Please don't forget to accept the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @JimmyPersson Did anything go wrong ?

Comment: @Sniffer yes, it does

Comment: @HamZa I tested it and it worked, the score is 1-0 to your advantage :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `^(?!.*Engineer).*$` with nothing - should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However, I had to install Notepad++ since it didn't work in Notepad2.